# Is there an item map for Rex Rocket?

Tags: rex-rocket

I recently finished Rex Rocket but I'm missing a few records and info nodes. Is there a map of where the records and other items are? A map with info nodes would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

I found a semi complete map [in this steam thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/288020/discussions/0/613958868359547825/). It's roughly 97% done as of July 14.

[image]

Thank you chronicles47!